# How to obtain concurrently in PHP using ReactPHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, reactphp, concurrently

I want to process multiple process in same time. I searched and found that this can be happen using the ReactPHP. I tried but could not successes. I added the Time of each process start/end time and results showed that each function's start time is not same. I want that starttime of each function should be same.

Here is my code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use React\Promise\Promise;

$loop = Factory::create();

function asyncTask($taskName)
{
    return new Promise(function ($resolve) use ($taskName) {
        $startTime = (int)microtime(true);
        echo "Starting $taskName at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startTime) . "\n";

        $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $loop->addTimer(rand(1, 5), function () use ($resolve, $taskName, $startTime) {
            $endTime = (int)microtime(true);
            echo "Completed $taskName at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endTime) . "\n";

            $resolve([
                'taskName' => $taskName,
                'startTime' => $startTime,
                'endTime' => $endTime,
            ]);
        });

        $loop->run();
    });
}

$promises = [
    'Task 1' => asyncTask('Task 1'),
    'Task 2' => asyncTask('Task 2'),
    'Task 3' => asyncTask('Task 3'),
];

\React\Promise\all($promises)->then(function ($results) {
    echo "All tasks completed: <br>";
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo "{$result['taskName']} started at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result['startTime']) . " and ended at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result['endTime']) . "\n";
    }
});

$loop->run();
?>
```

**and results are showing below as**
**Starting Task 1 at 2024-01-18 17:37:09**
Completed Task 1 at 2024-01-18 17:37:10
**Starting Task 2 at 2024-01-18 17:37:10**
Completed Task 2 at 2024-01-18 17:37:14
**Starting Task 3 at 2024-01-18 17:37:14**
Completed Task 3 at 2024-01-18 17:37:15
All tasks completed:
Task 1 started at 2024-01-18 17:37:09 and ended at 2024-01-18 17:37:10
Task 2 started at 2024-01-18 17:37:10 and ended at 2024-01-18 17:37:14
Task 3 started at 2024-01-18 17:37:14 and ended at 2024-01-18 17:37:15

**and I want to see each task's starting time as 2024-01-18 17:37:09**

Comment: Asynchronous != Parallel. There is still only one process/thread for userland code execution, but asynchronous tasks can potentially yield execution back to other code under certain conditions, resulting in more efficient use of processor time within a single process. Eg: When PHP does file/socket I/O it internally spins up a thread for it, and ReactPHP is written in such a way as to call them in non-blocking mode and yield execution back to the event loop while it waits for data. [IIRC]

Comment: Hi Sammitch,
Thanks a lot to comment on my question. :)
Will you please let me know how can I get the Parallel processing in PHP? I am using php 8.1.2 version, whats the latest way to obtain Parallel processing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ReactPHP core developer here.

A few things, first of we changed the way the event loop is used so that you only have to call `Loop::addTimer` in your case.

Secondly, you're creating a new event loop once at the top of your file, and then in every function call, so 4 times.

As pointed out by Sammitch, you are still doing all of this in one thread. So unless you want to start using `ext-parallel` or `react/child-process` you will still do everything in the same single core process. Unless you are doing CPU bound operations that single process won't be an issue. If you are doing CPU bound operations, child process can help you out.

With our `async` package, you can write your code the following:

```php
<?php

use React\EventLoop\Loop;
use React\Promise\Promise;

use function React\Async\async;
use function React\Async\await;
use function React\Promise\all;
use function React\Promise\Timer\sleep;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * @return array<string, float>
 */
function asyncTask($taskName): array
{
    $startTime = (int)microtime(true);
    echo "Starting $taskName at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startTime) . "\n";

    await(sleep(random_int(1, 5)));

    $endTime = (int)microtime(true);
    echo "Completed $taskName at " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endTime) . "\n";
    return [
        'taskName' => $taskName,
        'startTime' => $startTime,
         'endTime' => $endTime,
    ];
}

$promises = [
    'Task 1' => async(static fn () => asyncTask('Task 1'))(),
    'Task 2' => async(static fn () => asyncTask('Task 2'))(),
    'Task 3' => async(static fn () => asyncTask('Task 3'))(),
];

$results = await(all($promises));

echo 'All tasks completed:', PHP_EOL;
foreach ($results as $result) {
   echo "{$result['taskName']} started at ", date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result['startTime']), ' and ended at ', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result['endTime']), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: We are getting error on the below code \n

$promises = [
    'Task 1' => async(asyncTask('Task 1')()),
    'Task 2' => async(asyncTask('Task 2')()),
    'Task 3' => async(asyncTask('Task 3')()),
];
\n
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements**

Comment: Fixed a tiny mistake in the first task. Didn't test this code, just whipped out up quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot to reply and fixed tiny mistake.  But I am still getting error on line **Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: React\Async\async(): Argument #1 ($function) must be of type callable, array given, called** on code **'Task 1' => async(asyncTask('Task 1'))(),**
<br>
Will you please also fix this issue on code example?

Thanks

Comment: Found the issue and fixed it, also did some minor clean up